# Default Module installation issue in magento 2.3 in xampp

Tags: php, module, installation, magento-2.3

I am a novice in magento and of course in magento 2.
I have installed magento 2.3 in php 2.2 in xampp.
I have created a custom module which is a CRUD operation. That is working fine.
When I am trying to install a module (magento/module-shared-catalog) through the admin panel (System > Web Setup Wizard > Extension Manager(Extension Ready to install)), showing error like.

**1. Check Cron Scripts**

Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail

Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
Other checks will fail as a result (PHP version, PHP settings, and PHP extensions)

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet

For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.

**2. PHP Settings Check ***

For additional assistance, see PHP settings check help .

**3. PHP Extensions Check**

missing PHP extensions. Hide detail

The best way to resolve this is to install the correct missing extensions. The exact fix depends on our server, your host, and other system variables.
Our PHP extension help can get you started.

For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

I am trying in my local server(127.0.0.1).

To overcome the above cron issue, I have edited the following function in the following file

C:\xampp\htdocs\lapis\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Environment.php

in cronScriptAction()

**replace**

$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();

**to**

$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];

then cron issue have been fixed but the remaining two issues are still there as mentioned above.

Please assist me how to solve the issue and install any compatible module in my Magento 2.3 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! after googling I got the success both in windows and linux (Ubuntu).
I need to run the cron, before try to install module in magento.

Open terminal and enter the following line in the terminal.

```
cd <magento_root_directory>
```

then execute the following 3 commands in terminal.

```
php bin/magento cron:run

php update/cron.php

php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Then try to install the module from  magento 2.3 admin panel.